# Send multiple files in connect direct ndm parallely

Tags: zos, db2-zos, connect-direct, zos-connect-ee

I want to send huge files from Unix to zos node parallely can you help how to open multiple sessions and submit the ndm script any example code will be helpful to me

Is parallel transfer possible from Unix(node A) to mainframes (node B)

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: There is a tag here for [zos], so add that to your Q, but I think you'll get faster help if you look for other resources that focus on IBM products. The IBM support website used to be pretty good. Good luck.